# How to make the buttons visible on simulator?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1. I recently added a background image to my application but the buttons on the view controller aren't visible. When I remove the background image, the buttons become visible again. How to handle this?

Comment: read [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) first

Comment: I'm sorry. I still can't understand :/

Comment: I think your buttons are behind the imageview that's why when the image are there it is not visible, so put your imageview first then buttons.

Comment: yes I agree with @Indrajeet, you need to check the hierarchy of your subviews on view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not checking the view hierarchy, then do one thing create outlet of you button and then write following code in viewDidLoad.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Can you tell me how to bring the button label to front too?

Comment: I got it [self.view bringSubviewToFront:label]; thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if  you were used xib...

If you are using xib in your project, giving a background image for your button will more easy.

Place a button anywhere you want. Then go to attributes inspector on the right hand side. There you can find a field for changing your background image. Just give the name of your image.

Hope it will helpful for you